# Get the number of rows from $wpdb->get_results not working

Tags: wp-query, query

I want to count the number of rows of this custom wordpress query and it does not work:

*PS I am accessing a custom table inside my wordpress database, mabe by myself. The $wpdb->get_results part works.*

```
$myquery = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `$table` WHERE $myconditions"); 
$nr = $myquery->num_rows;
```

Any ideas why?

Important: using $wpdb->get_results like this:

- Do I need to prepare the query (i read it in the codex)?
- Do I need to somehow reset the query after I have used it?

Ty for helping!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing a Select Count(*) ... will only ever output one row with a single value - the number of rows that satisfied your where clause.